# Spring Boot Microservices Fetching Config from Server Over Https

Tags: spring-boot, https, microservices

We are switching over our microservice ecosystem from http to https.  I have been able to boot out Eureka Gateway Service in https and have our Config Service connect and register itself over https.

However, when I boot a third service that requires configurations, I cannot get the service to fetch the configs over https:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2018-09-06 15:03:21.260  INFO 2800 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://blah
```

I have researched several Spring Boot Https guides, and have tried many different combinations of configurations.  I will paste the bootstraps for the relevant services.  There may be some redundant info because I had tried so many different things.

bootstrap.yml for the Gateway Service:

```
server:
  port: 8761
  transport: https
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: serverkeystore.p12
    key-store-password: changeit
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: serverkey
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: https://localhost:8761/eureka
  server:
    enableSelfPreservation: false
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    statusPageUrl: "https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/info"
    healthCheckUrl: "https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/health"
    homePageUrl: "https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/"

security:
  require-ssl: true
```

bootstrap.yml for Config Service:

```
server:
  port: 8085
  transport: https
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: serverkeystore.p12
    key-store-password: changeit
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: serverkey

spring:
  application:
    name: config
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://localhost:8761/eureka

security:
  require-ssl: true
```

bootstrap.yml for Third Service:

```
server:
  port: 1111
  transport: https
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: serverkeystore.p12
    key-store-password: changeit
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: serverkey
spring:
  application:
    name: service
  cloud:
    config:
      failFast: true
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: config
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://localhost:8761/eureka

security:
  require-ssl: true
```

If anyone has had this same issue, please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on configuration in the question you are running your Config Server in https, but you should also register it in Eureka to be discovered as https. Otherwise Third service after doing discovery by serviceId will receive http URL from Eureka, so you should force your Config Server to register as https by using:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    statusPageUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}/info
    healthCheckUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}/health
    homePageUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}/
```

See: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_registering_a_secure_application

Comment: Ah, it appears I was putting these configs in my Gateway and not in my Services that are registering themselves.  I am getting a separate cert issue now, so I believe this is solved.